# Websocket disconnecting when app is on background (REACT NATIVE)

Tags: react-native, websocket

Im doing an "Uber like" app, and using a websocket to keep an eye on the driver (to get his location). Within 1~10 minutes (it varies) and on background, the connection dies, i'm guessing it's not the websocket, the onclose event doesn't even return anything. It's like something is force closing the app or something alike. Anyone has any clue on what is happening? I'm using Expo.

The websocket function is this one: (i'm using reconnecting-websocket)

```
 connect = () => {

var URL = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXxx';

var token = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';

var ws = new ReconnectingWebSocket(URL,token, { debug: true, reconnectInterval: 3000 });

ws.onopen = () => {

console.log('Entered!');

}

ws.onclose = () => {

console.log('Left!')

}

}
```

The "Entered!" is printed, the "Left!" isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Operating system is killing your app after some period in the background. You can use [Headless JS](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/headless-js-android) (Android only) to run some background tasks periodically (can't keep websocket connection active though) or things like [react-native-background-task](https://github.com/jamesisaac/react-native-background-task) or [react-native-background-fetch](https://github.com/transistorsoft/react-native-background-fetch) that work on both iOS and Android but are not able to run tasks more frequently than once per 15 minutes. To my knowledge, the only way to achieve what you want is to write separate native modules for Android and iOS suited for your needs (and that's still not guaranteed to work, as operating systems nowadays are eager to kill any battery draining background apps). Consider enforcing foreground mode for your app